# Google Map inside Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, accordion

I am trying to place a Google Map inside the Bootstrap Accordion.

When I put the map  `<div id="mapcanvas">` in the second accordion, the map does not load properly when I open the second accordion.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map-acc a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).collapse('show');
      resetMap(map);
    });
});

function resetMap(m) {
    x = m.getZoom(); alert('infunctin');
    c = m.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(m, 'resize');
    m.setZoom(x);
    m.setCenter(c);
};
```

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/rajumax/pen/bdqjXe)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGZJPy)

This js code will work for you.
I created a global map variable, because in your case it is not available when you call

```
reset(map);
```

js code

```
var map;

function gmap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.0827, 80.2707),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', gmap);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map-acc a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).collapse('show');
      resetMap(map);
      });           

    function resetMap(m) {
        x = m.getZoom(); 
        c = m.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(m, 'resize');
        m.setZoom(x);
        m.setCenter(c);
    };
});
```

Comment: thank you @yuyokk  i like to change .collapse class to .collapse .in please suggest how to do this in jqery?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you need. But I guess you need https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I ilke to write $(this).collapse .in ('show');                                                     .in is a class added to accordion  which one is clicke by user, so i like to check class collapse in and then trigger reset map function @yuyokk